# how do you echo global define variable inside of php?

Tags: php

This global define is being used as part of an email script.  the define in the global file is like this:

```
define ('BCC_EMAIL', "email@email.com");
```

Then in the email portion of a different file where you setup the headers (to, from, cc, and bcc), i wan't to use the global variable for the bcc line.  so first i only want the line to be used if the global variable is defined, then inside the headers line i want to echo the variable inside the quotes.  how do i do that?  here is what i think it would be, but this looks wrong:

```
if (BCC_EMAIL) {
    $headers .= ''.BCC_EMAIL.'' . "\r\n";
}
```

didn't get the bcc email with that suggestion.  does it matter how i'm including/requiring the global file?  all pages require a local config file like this:

```
require_once("local_config.php");
```

then the local config file requires the global config file like this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config/config_global.php");
```

does that mean that my BCC_EMAIL define never reaches my page?

Comment: This isn't a variable (global or otherwise), it's a constant

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues.

1. You need to use [`defined()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.defined.php) to check to see if a constant is defined
2. You need to either escape your quotes, use a combination of single and double quotes, or concatenation if you want a quoted string inside of a string (although you don't need them at all here).

Try this:

```
if (defined('BCC_EMAIL')) {
    $headers .= BCC_EMAIL."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: `defined` accepts a string, not a constant literal. And I guess the quotes can be left off entirely, the OP is just confused by them.

Comment: @deceze Indeed it does. Definitely a gotcha.

Comment: didn't get the bcc email doing it like this.  i updated my question.

Comment: Put an echo statement inside the if statement and see if you get there. If you don't then that constant is not available to your script and you need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was:

```
if (defined('BCC_EMAIL')) {
    $headers .= 'Bcc: '.BCC_EMAIL.'' . "\r\n";
}
```